# transform a table with top and side header in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that's currently in this format:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {
   201801 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, },
   201802 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, },
   201803 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, }, 
   201804 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, }, 
   201805 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, }, 
   201806 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, }, 
   201807 : {'A': 2.4, 'B': 3.4, 'C': 4.4, 'D': 5.4, }, 
   }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    201801  201802  201803  201804  201805  201806  201807
A     2.4     2.4     2.4     2.4     2.4     2.4     2.4
B     3.4     3.4     3.4     3.4     3.4     3.4     3.4
C     4.4     4.4     4.4     4.4     4.4     4.4     4.4
D     5.4     5.4     5.4     5.4     5.4     5.4     5.4
```

I would like to transform this table into this format:

```
201801      A   2.4
201801      B   3.4
201801      C   4.4
201801      D   5.4
201802      A   2.4
201802      B   3.4
201802      C   4.4
201802      D   5.4
201803      A   2.4
201803      B   3.4
201803      C   4.4
201803      D   5.4
201804      A   2.4
201804      B   3.4
201804      C   4.4
201804      D   5.4
```

How can I do this using Python Pandas?

Comment: Start by typing those images as text. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to ply with your data. Use the **{}** to format your tables as code so they align

Comment: Just use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html): `df=df.reset_index(); pd.melt(df, id_vars='index', var_name='year_month')`

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tried using table, but the format screws up.

Comment: try harder. it is possible. format as code - see my edit.

Comment: @Parfait want to make yours an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to convert your data from wide to long format.  You can transpose the data and then stack it:

```
df2.T.stack()

201801  A    2.4
        B    3.4
        C    4.4
        D    5.4
201802  A    2.4
        B    3.4
        C    4.4
        D    5.4
# ...
```

Alternatively, you can use `df2.stack().swaplevel()`, but this will order by the "letters" index, not the dates, by default.

Comparing the two, the first is much faster.

```
%timeit df2.T.stack()
693 µs ± 131 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df2.stack().swaplevel().sort_index()
2.64 ms ± 182 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, simply use pandas [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to reshape wide to long format:

```
# RESET INDEX AS A REGULAR COLUMN
df = df.reset_index()

# MELT WIDE TO LONG FORMAT
finaldf = pd.melt(df, id_vars='index', var_name='year_month')
```